# How can i do Calculation on an Auto Populated table,

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, database-trigger

This seems to be a basic question but I can't seems to figure it out

I'v got 2 tables: `table_a` and `table_b`

---

```
SELECT * FROM `table_a`
+----+--------+----------+
| id | a_item | a_values |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |        5 |
|  2 |      1 |        5 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM `table_b`;
+--------+-------+
| a_item | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |    10 |
+--------+-------+
# NOTE: total is TEN
```

---

As it shows I'm using a Trigger to SUM(a_values) from `table_a`, and store that results in `table_b`.
The trigger I am using is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER totaling
    AFTER INSERT ON table_a
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table_b(a_item, total)
        SELECT a_item, SUM(a_values) FROM table_a
        GROUP by a_item
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        total = VALUES(total);
    END
```

Now lets say, I update `table_b`:

```
UPDATE table_b
    SET total = total - 5
    WHERE a_item = 1

# NOTE: I'm subtracting FIVE from previous total which was TEN
```

and the result on `table_b` total column is 5, which is expected

```
SELECT * FROM `table_b`
+--------+-------+
| a_item | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |     5 |
+--------+-------+
```

Up to this point, everything is working accordingly
However when I do a insert on `table_a` the calculations goes off.
example:

```
INSERT INTO table_a(a_item, a_values) 
    VALUES
    (1, 5);
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM `table_b`;
+--------+-------+
| a_item | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |    15 |
+--------+-------+
# NOTE: see how the total has changed from FIVE to FIFTEEN, my expected result is TEN
```

I could fix this issue by directly updating on `table_a`, then the insert Trigger will only SUM with it's existing values which will give me my expected result.

the question is, is there a way where I could get the desired result without manipulating `table_a`, and only manipulating `table_b`, or do I need to change the insert Trigger ?

thanks.

Comment: Why would you directly update table_b?

Comment: I'd like to keep the data in table_a untouched,

Answer (score 1):

Consider not materializing the sum at all. Use a view instead, that provides the sum:

```
DROP TABLE table_b;

CREATE VIEW table_b
AS
SELECT a_item,
       sum(item_values) total
       FROM table_a
       GROUP BY a_item;
```

Then there's no need for any trigger and the sums will always be the accurate and current ones. Consistency is maintained all the time.

Comment: Yep, I want a simple query like this, how ever the thing is since we are using A SUM function on the query the query is not updatable, anyway this is v helpful. thanks

Comment: i would like to update the total column from `table_b`, but since it uses a sum function. it gets restricted

Comment: @Mattey: The point here is that you do not need to update the sum here. It is always the current sum from the other table.

Comment: yep, but what if  someone wants to update from the total in `table_b`, without them having to actually manipulate the data in `table_a`, is there a way??, the VIEW method is more interesting, to play around with the data, instead of manipulating on the original insert which is in `table_a`

Comment: @Mattey: So the sum in `table_b` doesn't necessarily reflect the sum of the values in `table_a` but, it should be possible that they differ? Well, then the main argument of a view -- ensuring integrity -- is pointless, if such integrity is explicitly not wanted.

Comment: oh ok, then its up to triggers

Comment: @Mattey - You want to say that you are a billionaire, even though your assets add up to only a few million?  Table_b is going to be the honest sum of table_a; why would you want lie about the sum?

Comment: @RIck James, first of all thanks for the joke :D, so with the answers here I'm guessing its a rule written in stone not to update my `table_b`... Actually on a serious note I would really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction on achieving what I'm looking for, or maybe tell me if I haven't made my self clear on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a `TABLE table_b` or a `VIEW table_b`?  You cannot have both.

A `TABLE` is a bunch of data sitting on disk.  A `VIEW` is not "materialized" (at least not in MySQL).  It is just syntactic sugar for reading the data in the underlying table(s).  Hence, the `VIEW` can *only* reflect what is *currently* in the underlying table.

You *read* a `VIEW` the same way you read a `TABLE`, namely with a `SELECT`.

When you add rows to the table, they are immediately there in the view.  The sum is immediately recomputed when you read the view.

OK, "Some views are updatable and references to them can be used to specify tables to be updated in data change statements. That is, you can use them in statements such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying table." (quoting the manual).  But don't do that.  At least not until you have a better handle of tables and non-updatable views.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have found a solutions, i will try to answer it on my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trigger you want is to maintain the sum in `b`, not to reset it.  That would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER totaling
AFTER INSERT ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_b (a_item, total)
        VALUES (new.a_item, new.total)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = total + VALUES(total);
END;
```

You probably also want an `UPDATE` trigger as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the problem was using a direct query on `table_b`.
instead of summing and grouping from `table_a`, that used a trigger, a procedure was used for insertion on both tables

It inserted/updated `table_b` in itself:

```
INSERT INTO table_b(a_item, total)
    SELECT a_item, total + @var FROM table_b WHERE a_item = @var2
    GROUP BY a_item
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    total = VALUES(total);
# NOTE: the arithmetic operator doesn't have to be an addition.
# NOTE: @var is used as in a broad sense(not necessary as a MySQL variable).
```

Hope I've made myself clear, and somebody finds this answer helpful.
cheers :)